# python regular expression, extract bytes from listing output

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the binary opcodes from listing file generated via /Fa flag in visual studio. The format look like:

```
00040   8b 45 bc     mov     eax, DWORD PTR _i$2535[ebp]
  00043 3b 45 c8     cmp     eax, DWORD PTR _code_section_size$[ebp]
  00046 73 19        jae     SHORT $LN1@unpacker_m
```

When the first number is address, then we have opcodes and then the instruction mnemonic, in such case I'd like to get an array of:

```
8b 45 bc 3b 45 c8 73 19
```

First I split the line and then run the following regular expression to get bytes:

```
HEX_BYTE = re.compile("\s*[\da-fA-F]{2}\s*", re.IGNORECASE)
```

But this regex match everything, someone have an idea how to do this in a simple way?
Thanks
David

Comment: You may read it line by line and use `^\d{5}\s+([\da-fA-F]{2}(?:\s+[\da-fA-F]{2})*)` to extract the opcodes into `group(1)` and then split with space and append the results to the list.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: There appear to be some whitespaces at the beginning in the second/third line.

Comment: @Jan: I change the format of the question, and I am not sure if those spaces are really there. OP is keeping silent.

Comment: I don't think that the leading spaces matter - the file uses a fixed width field format anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Forget regexp, it is over-complicated for extracting data from fixed fields. The statements

```
line = '  00043 3b 45 c8     cmp     eax,'
print(line[7:19].split())
```

yield

```
['3b', '45', 'c8']
```

You might need to

```
line = line.expandtabs()
```

first if there are <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters in the input strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one: `\s[\da-fA-F]{2}\s[\da-fA-F]{2}(\s[\da-fA-F]{2})?`

It would return three results for your example:

" 8b 45 bc"

" 3b 45 c8"

" 73 19"

You would have to split them with space and then you have the same result as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file sample in the question it appears to consist of fixed width fields, so you should be able to extract those values using fixed offsets into each line:

```
with open('listing.txt') as listing:
    opcodes = [opcode for line in listing for opcode in line[8:16].split()]

>>> opcodes
['8b', '45', 'bc', '3b', '45', 'c8', '73', '19']
```

The above uses a list comprehension to pluck out the required fields which are known to exist in positions 8 through 16 using nothing but a slice operation and a `split()`. This ought to be a great deal faster than a regular expression, and it *is* a great deal more readable.

If you want the opcodes as integers:

```
with open('listing.txt') as listing:
    opcodes = [int(opcode, 16) for line in listing for opcode in line[8:16].split()]

>>> opcodes
[139, 69, 188, 59, 69, 200, 115, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

A Python example with the help of regular expressions:

```
import re
string = """00040   8b 45 bc     mov     eax, DWORD PTR _i$2535[ebp]
  00043 3b 45 c8     cmp     eax, DWORD PTR _code_section_size$[ebp]
  00046 73 19        jae     SHORT $LN1@unpacker_m"""

bytes = map(str.strip, re.findall(r'((?:\b[\da-fA-F]{2}\b\s+)+)', string))
print bytes
# ['8b 45 bc', '3b 45 c8', '73 19']
```